# Session is created even after clearing cache

Tags: javascript, struts2, applet

On my struts2 application, User redirects to print page and clears cookies(or session timed out let us say), and on click of print button instead redirecting to login page it is creating new session. I checked in logs, it is going in HttpSessionListener and creating new session leading to toggle back on same page.
I am using Applet based printing.I have interceptors which will check is session is not available it will redirect to login page but in this case it is not coming in interceptor.
How I can avoid this and redirected to login page..?

Comment: Why note just check for a known value in the session? Not creating a session is actually more problematic.

Comment: How exactly your printing feature work? What happens when print button is clicked?

Comment: On click of button JavaScript function is called and it is calling method of Applet where Applet making call to servlet and getting bytes, same bytes we are printing using PrintService. And at servlet call it giving IOException. How can make it to go through interceptor?? @Dave it is good idea to check value in session and redirect to login page but I dont want it to do programatically.Is there a other way around??

Comment: So do you mean that your interceptors are not intercepting?

Comment: Yes, As it is not calling any *.action or *.jsp I think.

Comment: Do you really need direct printing? Maybe generate some pdf then user can print it whenever he/she want it. And pdf generation solves your problem with not logged users.